# Notification "read" status across devices

Tags: support

How is the notification which shows up as a red circle at the top left of the desktop version and the top right of the mobile version marked as "read"? Via cookie or a flag stored in the DB?

When I view the notification on my mobile device the indicator goes away... but when visiting the site via the desktop version the notification is there again.

Then when I drill into my account notifications are visible with a "unread" number indicator again under the "responses" area.

Comment: I haven't noticed that - I'm pretty sure it's working for me. I'll pay more attention next time though.

Comment: I think it's per _client_, but I'm going to double check for you.

Comment: Thank you. At present, I'm sometime clearing the same notification 3 times.